# angular-gettext does not work for escaped double quots

Tags: gettext, grunt-angular-gettext

We are using angular-gettext in our project and it's amazing tool, but there is one case I'm just frustrating on.
 In one template I have input with placeholder which also should be translated. For all the other placeholders it work like a charm, but this one contains double quotes:

```
<input placeholder='{{"Some text with \"quotes\"" | translate}}'>
```

and it doesn't work. angular-gettext can't translate it.
That was, actually, hard to just add this string as placeholder, because html parser doesn't accept quotes as `&quot;` or if swap double quotes with single quotes.

So, is there any solution/workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

Source text is traditionally written in en_US, and should therefore contain en_US punctuation.  This includes [quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark).

`<input placeholder='{{"Some text with “quotes”" | translate}}'>`

Your translators will substitute their own localised quotation marks.

> du texte avec « guillemets »